# npm stuck at "found 0 vulnerabilites

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx

This is where code is stuck

```
$ npx create-react-app myapp1                                                                                                                                                                                                npx: installed 99 in 69.254s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\bn803\onedrive\desktop\myapp1.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\bn803\onedrive\desktop\myapp1\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\bn803\onedrive\desktop\myapp1\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\bn803\onedrive\desktop\myapp1\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react@16.13.1
added 1606 packages from 750 contributors and audited 931196 packages in 629.367s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details       

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Does it finish to the point of being able to type in the terminal, or does it hang?

Comment: No it does not finished .Every time it hang at that point.I am using newer version of npm node npx.

Comment: If you exit the process with ctrl+c, does the install succeed? Might not be ideal but it's worth a shot.

Comment: No It does not succeed.After exiting process using ctrl+c when type npm start it give some script error .

Comment: Do you know the sollution?

Comment: No, sorry. Could be an issue with windows or security/permissions, but I don't use Windows much.

Comment: okay and thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that you go to cmd type resmon and at the time of running you will find cmd.exe suspended in processes so just resume but every single time you create the project you have to do this.